# Use of byte arrays and hex values in Cryptography

Tags: cryptography, hex, arrays

When we are using cryptography always we are seeing byte arrays are being used instead of String values. But when we are looking at the techniques of most of the cryptography algorithms they uses hex values to do any operations. Eg. AES: MixColumns, SubBytes all these techniques(I suppose it uses) uses hex values to do those operations. 
Can you explain how these byte arrays are used in these operations as hex values.

I have an assignment to develop a encryption algorithm , therefore any related sample codes would be much appropriate.

Comment: If you don't understand the concept of bytes, hexadecimal numbers and the relation between them you should NOT try to develop an encryption algorithm.

Comment: Sorry to say you are too rude, using all caps in a word in a bad ethic I suppose. And I just said I have an assignment to do, all I needed was some guidance, I didn't ask anyone to do my assignment either. If you still want to comment give me some links which will help me on understanding the relation between bytes and hexadecimal numbers. Thanks

Comment: The reason why you shouldn't develop an encryption algorithm is because it's damn difficult. As Schneier puts it: "Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break. It's not even hard. What is hard is creating an algorithm that no one else can break, even after years of analysis. And the only way to prove that is to subject the algorithm to years of analysis by the best cryptographers around.". With this in mind and your apparent lack of understanding basic concepts I strongly urge you to not accept the assignment.

Comment: Simple explination on byte and hexadecimals: One byte is an 8-bit value which can be represented in hexadecimal. A byte array is a series of hexadecimal values. Usually when you are encrypting you convert a string to a byte array (series of hexadecimal values) and do en cryptographic operations on the byte array (series of hexadecimal values).

Comment: firstly assignment, take it as a home work nothing else...
I have already done with the implementation. I know and have done some coding for substitutions, transpositions, permutations, and XOR. I have to do my documentation as well for this "home work". For that I need to understand really well how things happening inside.. By your last comments "string to a byte array (series of hexadecimal values)" this cleared almost everything.. I didn't think on that way (# of bits for byte and hex) :)

Comment: A byte array is _not_ a series of hexadecimal values - it's an array of bytes. Hexadecimal is a base system that's convenient for giving a human-readable representation of bytes, because two hexadecimal digits exactly represent one byte.

Answer (score 1):

Every four digits of binary makes a hexadecimal digit, so, you can convert back and forth quite easily (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Binary_conversion).

I don't think I full understand what you're asking, though.

Comment: Well what I'm concerned about is even though we pass a byte array for the encryption most of the time operations are done using hex values (eg. s-box in AES). So are these byte arrays are being convert back and forth to do the operations?(byte arrays to hex value arrays)
I'm asking this in-terms of encryption algorithms.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the algorithm; all hex algorithms can readily be converted back into byte-based algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to understand about hexadecimal is that it is a system for representing numeric values, just like binary or decimal.  It is nothing more than notation.  As you may know, many computer languages allow you to specify numeric literals in a few different ways:

```
int a = 42;
int a = 0x2A;
```

These store the same value into the variable 'a', and a compiler should generate identical code for them.  The difference between these two lines will be lost very early in the compilation process, because the compiler cares about the *value* you specified, and not so much about the *representation* you used to encode it in your source file.

Main takeaway: there is no such thing as "hex values" - there are just hex representations of values.

That all said, you also talk about string values.  Obviously 42 != "42" != "2A" != 0x2A.  If you have a string, you'll need to parse it to a numeric value before you do any computation with it.

Answer (score 0):

Bytes, byte arrays and/or memory areas are normally displayed within an IDE (integrated development environment) and debugger as hexadecimals. This is because it is the most efficient and clear representation of a byte. It is pretty easy to convert them into bits (in his mind) for the experienced programmer. You can clearly see how XOR and shift works as well, for instance. Those (and addition) are the most common operations when doing symmetric encryption/hashing.

So it's unlikely that the *program* performs this kind of conversion, it's probably the *environment* you are in. That, and source code (which is converted to bytes at compile time) probably uses a lot of **literals** in hexadecimal notation as well.

Comment: Not _entirely_ true - some things, such as the output of hash functions and key fingerprints are often represented in hex - so much so for hash functions that some people think hexadecimal strings are the output of SHA1!

Comment: @NickJohnson Yeah, I've seen those functions in e.g. PHP. I've also seen how they mess up everything, as you are constantly trying to guess if you are looking at bytes or hexadecimal ASCII. At least I know the difference, but if you look at the questions on stackoverflow, many people are wrong footed by such "convenience" methods.

Answer (score 0):

Cryptography in general except hash functions is a method to convert data from one format to another mostly referred as cipher text using a secret key. The secret key can be applied to the cipher text to get the original data also referred as plain text. In this process data is processed in byte level though it can be bit level as well. The point here the text or strings which we referring to are in limited range of a byte. Example ASCII is defined in certain range in byte value of 0 - 255. In practical when a crypto operation is performed, the character is converted to equivalent byte and the using the key the process is performed. Now the outcome byte or bytes will most probably be out of range of human readable defined text like ASCII encoded etc. For this reason any data to which a crypto function is need to be applied is converted to byte array first. For example the text to be enciphered is "Hello how are you doing?" . The following steps shall be followed:
1. byte[] data = "Hello how are you doing?".getBytes()
2. Process encipher on data using key which is also byte[]
3. The output blob is referred as cipherTextBytes[]
4. Encryption is complete
5. Using Key[], a process is performed over cipherTextBytes[] which returns data bytes
6 A simple new String(data[]) will return string value of Hellow how are you doing.

This is a simple info which might help you to understand reference code and manuals better. In no way I am trying to explain you the core of cryptography here.