# In a "C" program how can I store a hexadecimal value in a string variable?

Tags: c, encryption, des

I have a program which takes the input data as a plaintext and then decrypts the message using 3DES method in CBC mode. But the values are hardcoded in the program I want to provide the encrypted value myself which should be decryted. How can I do this in the following program?

```
int main(void)
{
    unsigned char in[BUFSIZE], out[BUFSIZE], back[BUFSIZE];
    unsigned char *e = out;
    int len;

    DES_cblock key;
    DES_cblock seed = {0xFE, 0xDC, 0xBA, 0x98, 0x76, 0x54, 0x32, 0x10};
    DES_cblock ivsetup = {0xE1, 0xE2, 0xE3, 0xD4, 0xD5, 0xC6, 0xC7, 0xA8};
    DES_key_schedule keysched;
    DES_cblock ivec;

    memset(in, 0, sizeof(in));
    memset(out, 0, sizeof(out));
    memset(back, 0, sizeof(back));

    RAND_seed(seed, sizeof(DES_cblock));

    DES_random_key(&key);
    DES_set_odd_parity(&key);
    if (DES_set_key_checked((C_Block *)key, &keysched))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Unable to set key schedule\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* 64 bytes of plaintext */

    /* From here, encryption starts for the plaintext below. */

    strcpy(in, "Now is the time for all men to stand up and be counted");

    printf("Plaintext: [%s]\n", in);

    len = strlen(in);
    memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));
    DES_ncbc_encrypt(in, out, len, &keysched, &ivec, DES_ENCRYPT);

    printf("Ciphertext:");
    while (*e) printf(" [%02x]", *e++);
    printf("\n");

    /* Till here, encryption is over. After this we have to decrypt
     * the value which has been encoded, but I want to remove all this
     * part and to provide my own encrypted message, and get the
     * proper output.
     */

    memcpy(ivec, ivsetup, sizeof(ivsetup));

    /* The problem I am facing is how to provide the value properly
     * to the parameter "out" and "keysched", which should be of my
     * choice. For "out" I want to provide THIS value:
     * "2DC39619B4450A8C27A3976C50DE5799".
     */

    DES_ncbc_encrypt(out, back, len, &keysched, &ivec, DES_DECRYPT);

    printf("Decrypted Text: [%s]\n", back);

    exit(0);
}
```

Read more: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/04/openssl-des-api.html#ixzz1uqOp1Yhv

Comment: do you just want to print the value?

Comment: NO. the function "DES_ncbc_encrypt" which is taking  care of the encryption and decryption is a library function. I just have to pass the values to the function properly. Not able to do that.

Comment: I printed the value of "out" once using %s and once in a while loop by iterating each address and then again by displaying using %x.
I got the following output:
Key= ffbfe7f0
Plaintext: [qwertyuiop[]asdf]

Length of plaintext: 16

 ivec before encryption:        ttxA

                                      0 \  J d

Ciphertext 1 : S ?  j   A  D.
 [53] [96] [19] [fb] [ce] [6a] [f8] [87] [d3] [41] [df] [ed] [44] [2e] [8c] [c5]

Ciphertext 2 : ffbfea00

 ivec before decryption:        ttxA

                                      0 \  J d
Decrypted Text: [qwertyuiop[]asdf]

Comment: To do the triple DES encryption/decryption I am using the openssl library functions like des_ncbc_encrypt(), which uses a key of 16 characters and a vector of 16 characters and implements single DES. I can call it 3 times and pass the values of the parameters and make it work as triple DES.
WhatI am doing is that I am removing the functions related to randomization and using my own hard-coded values of keys and vector for encryption in this way:

Comment: To do 3DES encryption/decryption I am using the openssl library functions like des_ncbc_encrypt(), which uses a key and a vector of 16 characters and implements single DES. I can call it 3 times and pass the values of the parameters and make it work as 3DES.
What I am doing is that I am using my own hard-coded values of keys and vector for encryption in this way:
    if (DES_set_key_checked((C_Block *)key, &keysched))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR1: Unable to set key schedule\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    DES_ncbc_encrypt(out, back, len, &keysched, &ivec2,DES_DECRYPT);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done.
I did it in a childish way for the time being but it is working now. I did it like this.

```
out[0]=0xA0; out[1]=0x69; out[2]=0x57; out[3]=0x3B;
out[4]=0x70; out[5]=0x26; out[6]=0x1C; out[7]=0xE8;
out[8]=0xEF; out[9]=0xF2; out[10]=0x9F;out[11]=0x60;
out[12]=0x80;out[13]=0x60;out[14]=0xB2;out[15]=0xE5;
```

Later I will do this thing in a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Read [C FAQ 20.10](http://c-faq.com/misc/hexio.html). Hexadecimal is a representation. All numbers are stored in binary internally. Your `DES_cblock` is probably a `typedef` for an (unsigned, perhaps!) integral type. So, what you have in effect is an array of integers. You can put numbers in decimal, hexadecimal or binary -- but they will all work. [Hexadecimal is typically used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800675/use-of-byte-arrays-and-hex-values-in-cryptography) in cryptography because it has some notational advantages.

Comment: DES_cblock is this:
typedef unsigned char DES_cblock[8];

and DES_key_schedule is a struct:
typedef struct DES_ks
{
    union
  {
   DES_cblock cblock;
   
   
   DES_LONG deslong[2];
  } ks[16];
} DES_key_schedule;

Comment: @Manas: Much as I had expected. You can pass either a decimal `254` or a hex `FE` and the program will work as expected. Don't worry about the representation. If you want, you can have those numbers in a file which you can read back in (using appropriate format flags for integers with `fscanf`) and then fill an array and pass it along.

Comment: I have a hexadecimal number of length 32 like this "DC4938C31B9E8B30F32FC0F5EC894E16". I tried to pass it in 2 ways: 
1)unsigned out[BUFSIZE]={0xA0,0x69,0x57,0x3B,0x70,0x26,0x1C,0xE8,0xEF,0xF2,0x9F,0x60,0x80,0x60,0xB2,0xE5};

2)strcpy(out,"539619fbce6af887d341dfed442e8cc5");
After trying both ways when I tried to display the variables, it didn't had anything stored inside it and didn't get any errors also.
Both didn't work. How do I pass such a value to an unsigned char variable?

Answer (score 0):

Using the nonstandard `itoa` function that stores the value it as a string, you can do the following:

```
char* hexstr = itoa(back,16); 

// print out a string
printf("Decrypted Text: [%X]\n", back);
```

Comment: `itoa()` is a nonstandard function, essentially `sprintf("%d")`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dump function like this:

```
hexdump(char *buff, int len) { 
  int i,tmp;
  for(i=0; i < len; i++) {
    tmp = buff[i] & 0xff; /** to avoid sign extension */
    printf("%02x",tmp);
  }
}
```

And use it.

```
hexdump(back,len);
```

If you have to write it in memory, you can use sprintf, but you may have to write your own binary to hex function.