# How to assign a hexadecimal value to an unsigned char variable in a C program

Tags: c, hex, unsigned-char

The hexadecimal value that I want to store in a variable is of length 32. 
"DC4938C31B9E8B30F32FC0F5EC894E16".
I also want to then print this value but I don't know the format specifier in printf for unsigned char.

Comment: Are you trying to store it as a string? Otherwise you will need an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: the variable that I am using has this declaration.
unsigned char out[512];

Comment: Please make your question a bit clearer! It's really hard to say what you want to achieve.

Comment: OK. I am having a program which is accepting a string of unsigned char which will be an encrypted message using 3DES mode. So I think I will have to pass the message in a hexadecimal format. I have given an example of the message in hex above.
This function will then decrypt the message which I have provided in this variable and will be the plaintext.

Comment: @Manas Do you mean it takes an *array* of uchar (e.g. `uchar[] k = {0xDC, 0x49, ...}`) or ...?

Comment: @Manas: You're happily tumbling through vocabulary, there. A string containing hexadecimal digits is one thing, a hexadecimal integer literal is another, and `printf()` can print a hexadecimal *format*, but it's still not quite clear what you want. Precision of language is a required skill in programming.

Comment: That's wat the problem is.. 
I have the value which I want to pass to the function I also know that it should be a string of unsigned char, but I am not able to assign it the value. I tried it in following 2 ways:
1) 1)unsigned out[BUFSIZE]={0xA0,0x69,0x57,0x3B,0x70,0x26,0x1C,0xE8,0xEF,0xF2,0x9F,0x60,0x80,0‌​x60,0xB2,0xE5}; 2)strcpy(out,"539619fbce6af887d341dfed442e8cc5");
but when I displayed this variable through printf("\nCiphertext 1 : %s\n",out);
printf("\nCiphertext 2 : %x\n",out);
, it was blank

Comment: If you people are not actually getting what I am trying to ask then please check out this link where I have discussed my question more specifically.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583023/in-a-c-program-how-can-i-store-a-hexadecimal-value-in-a-string-variable/10583186#comment13706390_10583186

Comment: @Manas: You mean the question where you weren't any clearer in your communication? I'd recommend returning to a couple of advanced programming tutorials, instead of fiddling with some crypto API... learn to walk before you run.

Comment: Thanks for so cool suggestions guys. I know I am not even fit to stand leave about running. But what I know is that If I am able to send the desired string to this parameter of the function, rest will be taken care of by the library function.

Comment: ...which you didn't tell us about. This question is an exact duplicate. Close.

Answer (score 2):

That's a string of 32 *characters*, being hexadecimal digits. That makes 16 *bytes*, or 128 *bits*.

m0skit0 told you how to store it in a string. If you actually want to store that in an integer, you'd need something like `unsigned long long intvar = strtoull( stringvar, NULL, 16 )` - provided "long long" on your machine can stomach 128 bits.

**But what you want is something completely different,** which became clear only after you linked to that other question. (It's really bad to take something out of context like that, *especially* if you are confused about what you're actually doing.)

If you take a look at the API documentation, you will see that the parameter you are looking at is a **pointer to DES_cblock**. That's not a string, and not an integer. Have a look at `seed` and `ivsetup` in that other question, how they are initialized, and *think* for a minute.

Comment: Why in the world are 32 characters 16 bytes? ;-)

Comment: @guitarflow 32 *hexadecimal digits* can represent 16 octets of information. (I am sure that was a rile ;-)

Comment: Ahhhh ... of course, I thought you were talking about the C string. Damnit... ;-)

Comment: But the function that I am using is expecting a parameter of type unsigned char and not unsigned long long.
Please guys check this link too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583023/in-a-c-program-how-can-i-store-a-hexadecimal-value-in-a-string-variable/10583186#comment13706390_10583186

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `char`. It's a string:

```
unsigned char* value = "DC4938C31B9E8B30F32FC0F5EC894E16";
printf("%s\n", value);
```

Also, if this is a number I strongly do not suggest you transforming it into a string or char, since strings are slower and prone to more coding errors than numbers.

Numbers represented as hexadecimal (and not hexadecimal numbers, all numbers are hexadecimal, it's just a representation of the value) do not have any characters. Again, it's a number. You can of course convert it to a string (as with any other number) but to do so you should have a strong reason (e.g. the algorithm you want to use is faster with strings than numbers).

I suggest you reading about [representation of numbers](http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html). A lot of new programmers have problems with this topic.